# Before update trigger with referential integrity in oracle 11g

Tags: triggers, oracle11g, onbeforeunload, referential-integrity, beforeupdate

I want to understand what does before update in trigger means.

I have a table called `DEPT_MST` where `DEPT_ID` is the primary key. It has 2 rows with `DEPT_ID` 1 and 2.

Another table `EMP` has columns `EMP_ID` as primary key and `EMP_DEPT_ID` which is a foreign key referencing `DEPT_ID` of `DEPT` table.

Now if I add before update trigger on `EMP` tables `EMP_DEPT_ID` column which will check if new value for `EMP_DEPT_ID` is present in master table `DEPT` if now then will insert new row with new `DEPT_ID` to `DEPT` table.

Now if I update `EMP_DEPT_ID` to 3 where `EMP_DEPT_ID` is 2 in `EMP` table it is giving integrity constraint violation error  parent not found.

So,

1. Does this mean that Oracle checks for integrity constraints first and then calls the "before update" trigger?
2. Then how can we bypass this check and call before update trigger?
3. What exactly does "before update" mean here?
4. How can I achieve above result by using triggers and not by using explicit PL SQL block?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-deferred foreign key constraints are evaluated before triggers are called, yes.

If you can declare the foreign key constraint to be deferrable (which would require dropping and re-creating it if the existing constraint is not deferrable)

```
ALTER TABLE emp
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_emp_dept (emp_dept_id) REFERENCES dept( dept_id )
  INITIALLY DEFERRED DEFERRABLE;
```

In your application, you can then set the constraint to be deferrable, run your `INSERT` statement causing the trigger to fire and insert the parent row.  Your foreign key constraint will be validated when the transaction commits.

An alternative to defining the constraint to be deferrable would be to rename the `emp` table to, say, `emp_base`, create a view named `emp` and then create an `instead of insert` trigger on `emp` that implements the logic of first inserting into `dept` and then inserting into `emp_base`.